# Denoise algorithm in weave

Tags: c++, image, algorithm

I'm making a program that denoises an image. It does this by converting the RGB values of the image into it's HSI values, then operates on the HSI values and converts them back into RGB. My problem is that for some reason, quite a bit of the image gets the wrong colors after the denoising (the denoising itself works).

I'm at a standstill now with no ideas what is causing it (except that it's probably in the conversion process between RGB and HSI somewhere), so do any of you fine gentlemen/women have any idea? Here's an example of a picture that turned out wrong (all the extra green color):

[image]

These are the formulas:

[image: formulas]

FYI the formula has one error, which is that if R==G==B then H and S should be set to 0. You'll see that in the code.

Here's my weave code for the two different conversion processes (RGB>HSI, HSI>RGB). Cos and acos values need to be in degrees, hence the addition 180/pi and pi/180. The i in G[i], etc. just refers to the pixel being converted (it loops through all the pixels in the picture).

To HSI:

```
translateToHSI = r"""
        for (int i=0; i<(m*n); i++)
        {
            I[i] = (R[i]+G[i]+B[i])/3;
            if (I[i] == 0)
            {
                S[i] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                float fl = fmin(R[i], G[i]);
                fl = fmin(fl, B[i]);
                S[i] = 1-(fl/I[i]);
            }
            float func = (R[i]-(G[i]/2.0)-(B[i]/2.0))/sqrt((R[i]*R[i])+(G[i]*G[i])+(B[i]*B[i])-(R[i]*G[i])-(R[i]*B[i])-(G[i]*B[i]));
            if (R[i]==G[i] && G[i] == B[i])
            {
                H[i] = 0;
                S[i] = 0;
            }
            else if (G[i]<B[i])
            {
                H[i] = 360-(acos(func)*180.0/3.14159265);
            }
            else
            {
                H[i] = acos(func)*180.0/3.1459265;
            }
        }
"""
```

to RGB:

```
    translateToRGB = r"""
            for (int i=0; i<(m*n); i++)
            {
                if (H[i] == 0)
                {
                    R[i] = I[i]+2*I[i]*S[i];
                    G[i] = I[i]-I[i]*S[i];
                    B[i] = I[i]-I[i]*S[i];
                }
                else if (H[i] < 120)
                {
                    float func = cos(H[i]*3.14159265/180)/cos(60-H[i]*3.14159265/180);
                    R[i] = I[i]+I[i]*S[i]*func;
                    G[i] = I[i]+I[i]*S[i]*(1-func);
                    B[i] = I[i]-I[i]*S[i];
                }
                else if (H[i] == 120)
                {
                    R[i] = I[i]-I[i]*S[i];
                    G[i] = I[i]+2*I[i]*S[i];
                    B[i] = I[i]-I[i]*S[i];
                }
                else if (H[i] < 240)
                {
                    float func = cos((H[i]-120)*3.14159265/180)/cos((180-H[i])*3.1459265/180);
                    R[i] = I[i]-I[i]*S[i];
                    G[i] = I[i]+I[i]*S[i]*func;
                    B[i] = I[i]+I[i]*S[i]*(1-func);
                }
                else if (H[i] == 240)
                {
                    R[i] = I[i]-I[i]*S[i];
                    G[i] = I[i]-I[i]*S[i];
                    B[i] = I[i]+2*I[i]*S[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    float func = cos((H[i]-240)*3.14159265/180)/cos((300-H[i])*3.14159265/180);
                    R[i] = I[i]+I[i]*S[i]*(1-func);
                    G[i] = I[i]-I[i]*S[i];
                    B[i] = I[i]+I[i]*S[i]*func;
                }
            }
    """
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB

Comment: @Galik Gentlewoman, then :U

Comment: @DieterLücking None of those are for HSI, and I already have the formula. This isn't really about "how do I do it", but "what am I doing wrong?"

Comment: what are the types of `R, G, B, H, S, I`?

Comment: @AntonSavin They're numpy.arrays of numpy.floats

Comment: @Galik hope you're content now!

Comment: Content and sober now* :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I wrote the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


void toHSI(float R, float G, float B, float& H, float& S, float& I) {
    I = (R+G+B)/3;
    if (I == 0)
    {
        S = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        float fl = fmin(R, G);
        fl = fmin(fl, B);
        S = 1-(fl/I);
    }
    float func = (R-(G/2.0)-(B/2.0))/sqrt((R*R)+(G*G)+(B*B)-(R*G)-(R*B)-(G*B));
    if (R==G && G == B)
    {
        H = 0;
        S = 0;
    }
    else if (G<B)
    {
        H = 360-(acos(func)*180.0/3.14159265);
    }
    else
    {
        H = acos(func)*180.0/3.1459265;
    }
}

void toRGB(float H, float S, float I, float& R, float& G, float& B) {
    if (H == 0)
    {
        R = I+2*I*S;
        G = I-I*S;
        B = I-I*S;
    }
    else if (H < 120)
    {
        float func = cos(H*3.14159265/180)/cos(60-H*3.14159265/180);
        R = I+I*S*func;
        G = I+I*S*(1-func);
        B = I-I*S;
    }
    else if (H == 120)
    {
        R = I-I*S;
        G = I+2*I*S;
        B = I-I*S;
    }
    else if (H < 240)
    {
        float func = cos((H-120)*3.14159265/180)/cos((180-H)*3.1459265/180);
        R = I-I*S;
        G = I+I*S*func;
        B = I+I*S*(1-func);
    }
    else if (H == 240)
    {
        R = I-I*S;
        G = I-I*S;
        B = I+2*I*S;
    }
    else
    {
        float func = cos((H-240)*3.14159265/180)/cos((300-H)*3.14159265/180);
        R = I+I*S*(1-func);
        G = I-I*S;
        B = I+I*S*func;
    }
}

int main() {
    for (int r = 0; r < 255; r += 10) {
        for (int g = 0; g < 255; g += 10) {
            for (int b = 0; b < 255; b += 10) {
                float r1, g1, b1, h, s, i;
                toHSI(r, g, b, h, s, i);
                toRGB(h, s, i, r1, g1, b1);
                if (fabs(r - r1) > 5 || fabs(g - g1) > 5 || fabs(b - b1) > 5) {
                    std::cout << r << ' ' << g << ' ' << b << " --> "
                        << h << ' ' << s << ' ' << i << " --> "
                        << r1 << ' ' << g1 << ' ' << b1 << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo for convenience](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8553829e495f0e09)

The first lines of output are:

```
0 20 0 --> 119.835 1 6.66667 --> -9.17128 29.1713 0
0 30 0 --> 119.835 1 10 --> -13.7569 43.7569 0
0 40 0 --> 119.835 1 13.3333 --> -18.3426 58.3426 0
0 50 0 --> 119.835 1 16.6667 --> -22.9282 72.9282 0
0 60 0 --> 119.835 1 20 --> -27.5138 87.5138 0
```

Now you can debug this code with any of the values which give wrong results and find where the bug is.

Comment: this is massively confusing me. Assuming it's a copypaste of my code, what is the output? RGB --> HSI --> RGB? So the RGB on both sides should be the same?

I have no idea what HSI values are correct for just inserting your own colors, though.

Comment: *IF* what I said/think is correct, that means blue always converts successfully, but not red or green. So red and green conversion screws up. That said, like I said, I have double checked these countless times. I may just be overlooking something in front of my face, but I think I need an outside perspective if that's the case. Been rereading these algorithms for almost 5 hours now without finding the problem. Since Blue always works, though (if I understood the output correctly), I assume the fault is in the "to RGB" code. Hue is 119.825, so it should be in the second if statement. 1/2

Comment: To me it definitely looks like the funcs screw up (or how I use funct to set R/G, since func isn't used in Blue - which doesn't screw up), but I don't know how. And I don't see how. Help? 2/2

Comment: Aahhhh. Okay, found it. I lack a parenthesis in the cosinus block of said function ( 60-H[i]*... should be -> (60-H[i])*... ). Thanks, your debug setup helped out. I've rewritten that func function like 20 times, how did I screw it up every single time?

Comment: @user2875994 I've just found it also, was going to update the answer. Good that you managed to find it yourself.

Comment: Although this is done, I'd just like to say thank you for finding it although it's not needed. It's great that people will help others who can't find the solution when they're stuck, and not just say "do it yourself".